# C++ Lambda capture and reference counted Windows Runtime objects

Tags: javascript, c++, c++11, uwp, c++-cx

I'm working on a UWP app that is using Javascript for the UI and logic code with some extensions in C++.
One extension is a WebP decoder.

The goal is to decode a WebP image in an IAsyncOperation from C++/Native code directly to an ImageData's data buffer.
I believe I'm having some problem with the lambda capture of a handle to an object of type WriteOnlyArray.

The C++ part:

```
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<bool>^
WebPDecoder::DecodeRgbaAsyncInto(const Platform::Array<byte>^ input, Platform::WriteOnlyArray<uint8>^ output, int stride) {
    return create_async([input, output, stride]() -> bool {
        auto data = WebPDecodeRGBAInto(input->Data, input->Length, output->Data, output->Length, stride);
        if (data == nullptr) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Javascript part:

```
// _this.decoder = Universal.WebP.WebPDecoder();
//
function decode(data, height, width, canvas) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.width = width;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
        var stride = imageData.data.length / height;
        _this.decoder.decodeRgbaAsyncInto(data, imageData.data, stride).then(function (success) {
            if (success == false) {
                reject(Error("Failed to decode WebP Image"));
                return;
            }
            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

With this code I get a crash after the lambda function has been called and is being destroyed. The crash is in __abi_winrt_ptr_dtor().
I am not sure why.

If I change to use a reference capture of the WriteOnlyArray as below the decoding works most of the time, but occasionally I get a crash because output seems to change to an invalid pointer.
    `return create_async([input, &output, stride]() -> bool {`

For this case I'm suspecting it is because the lambda capture does not increase the reference count of the WriteOnlArray object and it is released before/during lambda execution.

How can I force the object to be available until the lambda is finished?

Comment: Where did `output` come from? Also, not a bug but a style thing -- the "WinRT" way of naming your function would be more like `DecodeRgbaIntoArrayAsync(input, stride, output)`

Comment: It was a typo in the example. `output` was supposed to be `imageData`. Corrected the code above.

This is my first experience with WinRT so not familiary with naming conventions yet. Thanks!

Comment: Btw:  I found some mention about arrays and async functions in the free Microsoft Press ebook "Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS and Javascript":

Page 1028:
"Furthermore, arrays cannot be effectively used with async methods,
because an output array will not be transferred back to the caller when the async operation is complete."

I assume this is still true thought this book is a couple of years old...

Comment: That's likely. Have you looked at IBuffer instead?

Comment: I was hoping that WebPDecoder::DecodeRgbaAsyncInto() would be able to write directly to image data buffer. This does not seem to work.

I now switched to allocate the buffer in the C++ function and return it as an IBuffer...